Heroku Bucketeer CORS To add S3 to your app without creating an AWS account, see the Bucketeer
Article has name
To add S3 to your app without creating an AWS account, see the Bucketeer add-on.
So how to resolve CORS ??
I added Bucketeer. I configured my app with that credentials
BUCKETEER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
BUCKETEER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
BUCKETEER_AWS_REGION
BUCKETEER_BUCKET_NAME

Then I faced with CORS error when try to open my attachment file. In your documentation you say
CORS Settings
Bucketeer credentials give you full access to modifying your bucket. This means that you can upload a new CORS policy at any time via an S3 client and the PUT Bucket CORS endpoint.

See example below.

Ok, I did it. I clicked to PUT Bucket CORS which redirected me to
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketCors.html
and what I see here, example
PUT /?cors HTTP/1.1
Host: Bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Content-MD5: ContentMD5
x-amz-sdk-checksum-algorithm: ChecksumAlgorithm
x-amz-expected-bucket-owner: ExpectedBucketOwner

But Heroku did not provide ChecksumAlgorithm, ExpectedBucketOwner
I was look on GetBucketCors
GET /?cors HTTP/1.1
Host: Bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-expected-bucket-owner: ExpectedBucketOwner

the same issue, where I should take value ExpectedBucketOwner for header x-amz-expected-bucket-owner
curl --location 'https://bucketeer-5a7f7a9b-c93f-4b05-9e7e-835d595eacae.s3.amazonaws.com/?cors=null'
--header 'Host: Bucket.s3.amazonaws.com'
--header '???????'

I tested with
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidBucketOwnerAWSAccountID</Code>
    <Message>The value of the expected bucket owner parameter must be an AWS Account ID... [....]</Message>
    <RequestId>....</RequestId>
    <HostId>....</HostId>
</Error>

Please provide correct user guide what I should to do with that service which I paid but it's not working like expected

I figured out how to resolve cors issue which I had. First of all need to have that library and there's an example of how to set cors conf
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/php/example_code/s3/PutBucketCors.php
By default cors config empty. When PutBucketCors was executed with allow origin * then URL for each file will be able to read
